# How do I make a column from substring of another column in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` with the column `ReleaseDate`, a Factor column with data like this:

```
Apr 10, 2001
Apr 10, 2007
...
```

I want to make a new column `ReleaseYear` with only the year, which is always the last four characters in the `ReleaseDate` data.

How do I get the last four characters from `ReleaseDate` for `ReleaseYear`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two options, one use the `year` from `lubridate` package, another use regular expression:

```
library(lubridate)
year(as.Date("Apr 10, 2001", format = "%b %d, %Y"))
[1] 2001

library(stringr)
str_extract("Apr 10, 2001", "\\d{4}$")
[1] "2001"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one option. gsub will return everything after ", ".

```
a <- c("Apr 10, 2001", "Apr 10, 2007")
df <- data.frame(a)
colnames(df) <- "ReleaseDate"
df$ReleaseYear <- gsub("^.*?, ","",a)
```

This is an alternative.

```
df$ReleaseYear <- substr(df$ReleaseDate, 9, 12)
```

One more option.

```
library(stringr)
df$ReleaseYear <- str_sub(df$ReleaseDate, -4)
```

Answer (score 2):

use substr.  substr(x, start, stop).  your start will be the length of df -4.

```
substr(df, nchar(df)-4,4)
```